# Passing quoted parameter to prepared statement PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I checked other questions, PHP and PDO documentation and many other examples, but I feel stuck, probably since I'm just getting started with PHP and MySQL.

I'm trying to first check if a line exist with a `SELECT` statement and then if line exists `DELETE` it.

However, the query is not going through, I'm using MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 18, and the queries work only with the single quotes after the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT bookname FROM libri WHERE bookname LIKE "test.pdf";
DELETE FROM libri WHERE bookname LIKE "test.pdf";
```

However seems like i'm unable to reproduce it with the prepared statements:

```
$sql = "SELECT bookname FROM libri WHERE bookname LIKE :deleteTerm;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':deleteTerm', $deleteKey); 
$stmt->execute();
```

I set `$deleteKey` as `$deleteKey = $_POST['delete'];` and trying to attach the single quotes as `$stmt->bindValue(':deleteTerm', "'".$deleteKey."'");` it's not working.
Also tried to set quotes directly into variable name: `$deleteKey = "'".$_POST['delete']."'";` and using the prepared statement above, but still not working.

Am i missing something,or getting something wrong? Maybe I have to use another query?

Comment: prepared statements don't need quotes, it takes the hole content of the variable as string, that is why sql injection doesn't work

Comment: Hi nbk, thank you for the comment and the confirmation, after checking back again at the code, I was able to actually make it work with `$deleteKey = $_POST['delete'];`

Answer (score -1):

"select" part of the transaction you have done is unnecessary. because you mean delete it if it exists. you are trying to delete it in the next section. if you actually run the second part directly, it will delete it if it already exists.I also recommend you to try this in the clawed area.

```
$sql = " DELETE FROM libri WHERE bookname LIKE 'test.pdf'";
```

Comment: i think the user meant something different., besides you will have to escape the quotes with \

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply but i wasn't asking if the queries are useful or not, question was about single quote escaping.